# Understanding the usage of bitbake between image and component

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Familiarizing myself with embedded linux, and came across `bitbake` command, which seemingly is a build tool for embedded linux applications in particular.

I'm trying to distinguish between `bitbake <image>` as opposed to `bitbake <component>` while adding that component to the config file.

For e.g: `bitbake <some_image>`, and the `conf/local_conf` file is modified to include the following:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "pciutils"
```

which should include `pciutils` in the image, as opposed to just running:
`bitbake pciutils`, which I reckon just compiles the component itself?

Does the former action actually mean `pciutils` is "supported" when the image is actually run on a HW, whereas the latter just compiles the component and doesn't do anything else.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: IMHO, yes it is.

Comment: One additional difference is that in the former example you are adding _package_ to your image. With the latter command you are compiling a _recipe_ pciutils. A recipe typically builds a package of the same name, but might build other packages as well.

Comment: so adding packages to an image really means the built will contain those packages and should be ready to use. For instance, I should be able to use `pciutils` in the terminal once the image is loaded, yes? Similar to how I'd be able to use `pciutils` in the terminal after just compiling a recipe `pcutils`?